# Program to find a intersection b of two arrays reads more elements than specified

Tags: arrays, c, nested-loops

I wrote a program to find a intersection b of two arrays in C.
My array is not taking the number of elements which I want to enter. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>;

int main() {
    int a[100], b[100], n, m, i, j;
    printf("enter n.o of ele to enter in A  \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("enter elements into array A:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d \n", &a[i]);
        
    }
    printf("enter n.o of ele to enter in B  \n");
    scanf("%d ", &m);
    printf("enter elements into array B:\n");
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        scanf("%d \n", &b[j]);
    }
    printf("common ele are :\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                printf("%d \n", a[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the program to output common elements in the arrays, but it is not taking the number of elements I want it to.
If I want to enter 4 elements into the array it is taking more than 4.

Answer (score 0):

In testing out your code, the main issue is in the formatting used within the "scanf" function calls.  For instance, the following scanf call was getting confused having the newline character included within the formatting.

```
scanf("%d \n",&a[i]);
```

Having perused your code, following is a refactored version with some cleanup of the scanf functions along with a bit of additional output text to make the program a bit more user friendly.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[100],b[100],n,m,i,j;
    printf("enter n.o of ele to enter in A  \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter elements into array A:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Element: ");    /* To provide some user friendly prompting */
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);     /* Clean up of the scanf formatting        */
    }

    printf("Enter n.o of ele to enter in B  \n");
    scanf("%d",&m);             /* Clean up of the scanf formatting        */
    printf("Enter elements into array B:\n");

    for(j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        printf("Element: ");    /* To provide some user friendly prompting */
        scanf("%d", &b[j]);     /* Clean up of the scanf formatting        */
    }
    printf("Common ele are :\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {

        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==b[j])
            {
                printf("%d \n",a[i]);
                //break;        /* Should not want this if all matches are to be printed */
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that items such as the newline character and space padding was removed.  With those bits of refactoring, following was a test of the refactored code.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Intersect/bin/Release$ ./Intersect 
enter n.o of ele to enter in A  
3
enter elements into array A:
Element: 44
Element: 88
Element: 77
Enter n.o of ele to enter in B  
3
Enter elements into array B:
Element: 77
Element: 55
Element: 88
Common ele are :
88 
77
```

You might want to do a bit more study of the scanf function, but give this refactored code a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Removing the `break;` is counterproductive: for `1 1`, `1 1` the output becomes `1 1 1 1`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `scanf()` conversion strings: the call `scanf("%d \n", &a[i]);` is executed with the following phases:

- `%d` reads bytes from `stdin`, ignores any initial white space, accepts an optional sign and converts all subsequent digits as an `int` in base 10, which is stored into `a[i]`. then
- causes `scanf` to read and discard any whitespace characters. The newline entered is consumed and further input is expected from the user until a non-whitespace character is typed in (this character is pushed back into `stdin`) or the end of stream is encountered.
- `\n` has exactly the same effect, hence does nothing more as the pending character is not whitespace.

The trailing  `\n` is the culprit: each call to `scanf()` does not return until the first character of the next number os typed.  Just remove these characters and the program should behave as expected.

Note however that you should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input.

Note also that the trailing `;` after the `#include <stdio.h>` is invalid.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[100], b[100], n, m, i, j;

    printf("enter number of elements to enter for A:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (n < 0 || n > 100) {
        printf("invalid number of elements: %d\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("enter elements into array A:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    printf("enter number of elements to enter for B:\\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &m) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (m < 0 || m > 100) {
        printf("invalid number of elements: %d\n", m);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("enter elements into array B:\n");
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (scanf("%d \n", &b[j]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    printf("common elements are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                printf("%d\n", a[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the above algorithm does not deal with duplicates correctly:

- for the sets `A = { 1, 1 }` and `B = { 1 }`, the output is `1 1`, which is not even a subset of `B`.  The output should be `1`.

You can correct this problem with an extra array:

```
    unsigned char seen[100] = { 0 };
    printf("common elements are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j] && !seen[j]) {
                seen[j] = 1;
                printf("%d\n", a[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```